# Showing multiple table jasper report via spring

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, controller, jasper-reports

I am new in Jasper report.
I successfully displaying one table with jasper report. 
But how to display multiple table in jasper report via Spring Controller?

I'm not using database as data source, just plain POJO in ArrayList.

This is my Spring configuration

```
@Configuration
public class JasperReportConfig {

    @Bean
    public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
      JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
      resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/reports/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jrxml");
      resolver.setViewNames("report_*");
      resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
      resolver.setOrder(0);
      return resolver;
    } 

}
```

And this is my Controller.

```
@Controller
public class MyReportController {

    @RequestMapping("/thereport")
    public ModelAndView showReport(ModelAndView mv) {


        // the first list to be the first table
        List<Person> theFirstList = new ArrayList<>();
        theFirstList.add(new Person("Joni", "Jakarta"));
        theFirstList.add(new Person("Michel", "Singapore"));
        mv.addObject("dataSource", theFirstList);

        // the second list to be the second table
        List<Person> theSecondList = new ArrayList<>();
        theSecondList.add(new Person("Annie", "Thailand"));
        theSecondList.add(new Person("Barry", "India"));
        mv.addObject("dataSource", theSecondList); 

        mv.addObject("format", "pdf");
        mv.setViewName("report_address");

        return mv;
    }

}
```

Person class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private String address;

}
```

How to define a different dataSource so that i can use two (or more) list in report? Or maybe i can use one dataSource that contain multiple list in it?

Answer (score 1):

I Think it is better to use subdataset like this:
In your controller:

```
   JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(distinctSymbolRespCounts);            
            parameterMap.put("DS1", beanColDataSource);
```

In Your jrxml:

```
<parameter name="DS1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
```

When Defining table use this dataset:

```
  <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="Blank">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="datasourceTable" uuid="95223e22-f4cd-4749-9f65-6fa4b068a27b">
                                <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                            </datasetRun>
...
</jr:table>
```